# AWS sporadic "could not connect to endpoint" s3 & sts

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a couple of (python) scripts running every 15 minutes, about 99% of the time they run without issues but in that 1% of cases it has the following issue:

```
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/path/file.txt"
```

or

```
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://sts.amazonaws.com/"
```

Multiple checks run at the same time, lets call them

- check1.1
- check1.2
- check1.3
- check1.4

In the past 30 days, 1.1 has failed 1 time, 1.2 never, 1.3 has failed with the sts error twice, 1.4 has failed twice.

The code is in all instances the same, the only difference is that they try to assume different roles.

A couple of threads I've read pointed to the config not being correct, but if that was the case why does it only fail this 1%? Just in case this is the file from which it pulls it's profile settings:

```
{
  "key_id": "MYSECRETKEYID",
  "key_secret": "MYv3ryS3cur3K3y",
  "region": "eu-west-1"
}
```

These get used in the following code:

```
# open the credential file
credfile = open("myfile.json", "r").read()
json_obj_cred = json.loads(credfile)
awsaccesskeyid = json_obj_cred['key_id']
awssecretaccesskey = json_obj_cred['key_secret']
awsdefaultregion = json_obj_cred['region']

bucket = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=awsaccesskeyid,            
    aws_secret_access_key=awssecretaccesskey,   
    region_name=awsdefaultregion)
```

Do you guys have any idea what this could be or where i should start looking?

Comment: Are all these calls being made from an EC2 instance in the same region as the target? The safest option would be to have your code re-try. Even rare things can happen if you do them often enough.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, they run from docker instances in an ECS cluster in the same region. But good point on the retry.

Comment: @superstienos: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @ShantanuGupta Never found out why this happened, wrote it off as the "best effort" policy of AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if multiple scripts are reading the same s3 file this maybe the result